# Can I apply Lions--Aubin lemma on $X_0 \subset X \subset X_1$ with $X\equiv X_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The lemma is

> Let $X_0$, $X$ and $X_1$ be three reflexive Banach spaces with $X_0 \subset X \subset X_1$. Suppose $X_0$ is compactly embedded in $X$ and $X$ is continuously embedded in $X_1$. Let for non-infinite $p$ and $q$
>   $$W = \{ u \in L^p ([0, T]; X_0) | \dot{u} \in L^q ([0, T]; X_1) \}.$$
>   Then this compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;X)$.

I just want to check that I can pick $X=X_1$ here. I have in mind $L^2 \subset H^{-1} \subseteq H^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't see any problem with $X = X_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. In fact, the assumption is stronger the smaller $X_1$ is (smaller space has bigger norm, hence it's more difficult to be bounded in that norm). So for the purpose of verifying assumptions one could take some large space for $X_1$ (like $H^{-10}$, if you will) with no penalty in the result. This suggests that there may be a form of the lemma that does not need $X_1$ at all.

The assumption of reflexivity is not needed either, by the way. The sharp (*if and only if*) form of this lemma was proved by Jacques Simon in  much-cited paper *Compact sets in the space $L^p(O,T;B)$* which is [available from his webpage](http://math.unice.fr/~jsimon/pubs/Simon-E3.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!!! "This suggests that there may be a form of the lemma that does not need $X_1$ at all. " That's really interesting!