# Sobolev embeddings on vector-valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

So, this question is a bit of a follow up to this one:
[Can I apply Lions--Aubin lemma on $X_0 \subset X \subset X_1$ with $X\equiv X_1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818255/can-i-apply-lions-aubin-lemma-on-x-0-subset-x-subset-x-1-with-x-equiv-x-1?rq=1)

> Let $X_0$, $X$ and $X_1$ be three reflexive Banach spaces with $X_0 \subset X \subset X_1$. Suppose $X_0$ is compactly embedded in $X$ and $X$ is continuously embedded in $X_1$. Let for non-infinite $p$ and $q$
> $$W = \{ u \in L^p ([0, T]; X_0) | \dot{u} \in L^q ([0, T]; X_1) \}.$$
> Then this compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;X)$.

The question here is, can I apply Lions-Aubin lemma on $X_0 \hookrightarrow X \hookrightarrow X_1$ with $X_0= X$? If not in general, then can I make some assumptions on the spaces to make it work?

Edit: I do just want to clarify that I think that a space to be "compactly embedded in itself" sounds very weird, but I also don't see why $H^1([0,T];X)$ should not be compactly embedded into $L^2([0,T];X)$. Perhaps it's something wonky going on with dimensionality here, so what if $X$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: If $X_0=X$ then $X$ has to be compactly embedded into itself, which sounds strange.

Comment: Yeah, exactly... But at the same times, it feels really weird that $H^1([0,T],X)$ should not be compactly embedded into $L^2([0,T],X)$...

Comment: This cannot work: take bounded sequence $(x_k)$ in $X$ that has no convergent subsequence. Now define $x_k(t)=x_k$ (constant in time). Then $(x_k)$ is bounded in $H^1(0,T,X)$ but not converging in $L^2(0,T,X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactly embedded means: the identity map on $X$ if considered as map from $X$ to $X_0$ is compact. Now if $X=X_0$ this is exactly the case when $X$ is finite-dimensional.

The embedding $H^1(0,T;X)$ into $L^2(0,T;X)$ is not compact if $X$ is infinite-dimensional:
Take bounded sequence $(x_k)$ in $X$ that has no convergent subsequence. Now define $x_k(t)=x_k$ (constant in time). Then $(x_k)$ is bounded in $H^1(0,T,X)$ but not converging in $L^2(0,T,X)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But just to check, if I work in finite-dimensional spaces, it will be fine to take X_0=X=X_1?

Comment: If everything is finite-dimensional, then there is no problem.